# Function imwrite on imageio (Python) seems to be rescaling image data

Tags: python-imageio

The function imwrite() on imageio (Python) seems to be rescaling image data prior to saving. My image data has values in the range [30, 255] but when I save it, it stretches the data so the final image spreads from [0, 255], hence creating "holes" in the histogram so as increasing overall contrast.

Is there any parameter to fix this and make imwrite() not to modify the data?

Thanks

So far I am setting a pixel to 0 to prevent this from happening:

```
prediction[0, 0, 0] = 0
```

(prediction is a [1024, 768, 3] array containing a colour photograph)

```
imageio.imwrite('prediction.png', prediction)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! I was using uint32 values instead of uint8, then imwrite() seems to perform some scaling corrections because it expects uint8 type. The problem is solved using:

```
prediction = np.round(prediction*255).astype('uint8')
```

Instead of converting to 32-bit integer, which I did at the beginning:

```
prediction = np.round(prediction*255).astype(int)
```